# Module not found: Can't resolve 'heatmap-calendar-react'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github, npm, heatmap

I've created a component that worked fine in my local App, but I'm trying to get it work on npm and I am getting this error:

```
./src/App.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'heatmap-calendar-react' in 
'C:\Users\account\app\src'
```

Could somebody please take a look at my repository and help me understand what the issue may be?

https://github.com/willfretwell/heatmap-calendar-react

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, I had a typo in the main declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Add an `index.js` at the root, and have it import/export `/src/index.jsx`

Comment: Same problem, could there be anything else I'm missing?